# Accessing a counter in a variable name in Javascript (code inside)

Tags: javascript, variables, padding

I am looking to do something very similar to the following PHP code but in javascipt:

```
for ($weenumber = 1; $weenumber <= 30; $weenumber++)
{ 
    $weenumber = str_pad($weenumber, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo $_POST["entry{$weenumber}_cash"];
}
```

Basically accessing the loop number padded with a trailing 0 if less than 10 but I dont know the syntax in JS to do this :(

Sorry for noob style question

Comment: You mean "padding with a *leading* `0` if less than 10", right?

Comment: Thats one part of it, the main thing is the syntax to reference a variable inside a variable : entry{$i} in PHP would give : entry01 for instance

Comment: Google what exactly Jon? I did try "referencing variables in javascript" et al with no joy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you mean a leading zero rather than a trailing zero...

You can for example use the conditional operator:

```
(n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n
```

You could also implement a general purpose function:

```
function padLeft(str, len, ch) {
  while (str.length < len) str = ch + str;
  return str;
}
```

To access an object property by name in Javascript you use brackets. Example:

```
var value = obj['entry' + (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n + '_cash'];
```

If `n` contains `4`, this will be the same as `obj.entry04_cash`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help from everyone and of course Guffa. Really love this site and the people who help out :) Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not there's a specific function to do this, if you know how to use an `if` clause, and you know how to perform string concatentation (using the `+` operator if you didn't), then you should be able to easily roll you own version of `str_pad` by hand (which works for numbers below 100).

Think about the cases involved (there are only two) and what you need to output in either case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you should use:

```
for(var i=0; i<30; i++){
    document.writeln(i<10 ? "0"+i : i);
}
```

change document.writeln() with any function you want to handle the data

Answer (score 0):

```
for (weenumber = 1; weenumber <= 30; weenumber++) { 
    weenumber = str_pad(weenumber, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

For the str_pad() function, you can use PHPJS library:
http://phpjs.org/functions/str_pad:525

This library will also ease transition from php to javascript for you. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<30; i++)
{
   var index = i;
   if(i<10) index = "0" + index
   var elem = document.getElementById("entry"+index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function you can use for zeropadding:

```
function zeroPad(nr,base){
        var  len = (String(base).length - String(nr).length)+1;
        return len > 0? new Array(len).join('0')+nr : nr;
}
//usage
alert(zeroPad(3,10)); //=> 03
```

or extend the Number prototype

```
Number.prototype.zeroPad = Number.prototype.zeroPad ||
    function(base){
            var nr = this, len = (String(base).length - String(nr).length)+1;
            return len > 0? new Array(len).join('0')+nr : nr;
    };
//usage
var num = 1;
alert(num.zeroPad(100)); //=> 001
```

Now for the variable name part: if it's a global variable (not advisable) that variable is a property of the `global object`, in a browser that's `window`. You can get a variable by its dynamic name using the equivalent of: `window['myvariable'+myJustResolvedNumericValue]`. Within an object (instance) you can use the same bracket notation: `myObject['myvariable'+myJustResolvedNumericValue]`.

Using this information, in javascript your function could look like:

```
for (var weenumber = 1; weenumber <= 30; weenumber++)
{ 
    // execute something using the variable that uses the counter in the
    // variable name as parameter
    executeSomeFunction(window['entry'+weenumber.padLeft(10) + '_cash']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var someArray = [/*...*/];
for (var i= 1;i<= 30;i++)
    { 
        var weenumber = i+"";
        for(var j=weenumber.length;j<2;j++)
            weenumber = "0" + weenumber;
        var key = "entry" + weenumber + "_cash";
        document.write(someArray[key]);
    }
```